# Logging user and power activity Synology DiskStation (v5)

Tags: logging, network-attached-storage, synology

Is there any practical way of logging user activity and power state changes on a Synology NAS? I'm not looking for anything very extensively detailed, but I would like to log e.g. Video Station usage duration, or when the NAS sets itself to low power consumption state.

Thank you

Comment: you want it to monitor itself or be monitored from elsewhere?  SNMP can probably give you the info you are looking for.  I am not familiar with the Synology product line, but they support SNMP.  http://ukdl.synology.com/download/Document/MIBGuide/Synology_DiskStation_MIB_Guide.pdf is the link to the MIB guide for it.  

Keep in mind, if you try to write to a log when the disks go to sleep, it will have to wake up and reset the idle timer for the disks.  Of course, hopefully Synology would not have done it that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. When I meant practical way, what I meant was something along I'm not network/hardware savvy. So basically I want to monitor it myself, but I have no clue on how to achieve this. Ideally there would be some sort of app that I could install to do something similar. Thank you!